# Sending two parameters/data in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this code which posts data to a page and returns data. This is done through javascript. I want to post to different pieces of data from the form, the url which is already there and a hidden user field. Here is the code;

function go(url)   {

```
$.post('urlin.php', { url : url }, function(data ) {

if (data== 'error_no_url'){

    $('#message').html('<p>Try entering an actual URL!</p>');


    } else if (data == 'error_roll') {

    window.open('http://1227.com');
    $('#message').html('<p>ROFL</p>');

} else if (data == 'error_invalid_url') {

    $('#message').html('<p>Not a valid URL</p>');

} else if (data == 'error_is_min') {


$('#message').html('<p>Already a short URL, it can\'t get any shorter!</p>');   

} else {

    $('#url').val(data);
    $('#url').select();
    $('#message').html('<p> URL Shortened </p>');       
}

});
```

}

and;

```
<p><input type="text" size="85" placeholder="Enter a URL to shorten." name="url" id="url" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) { go($('#url').val()); }" /><input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['auth']; ?>"><input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Shorten" border="0" onclick="go($('#url').val());" />
```

At the moment it only posts the url. How can i get it to post the user aswell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would maybe do something like this...

```
 <input type="submit" onclick="javascript:go()">
```

and your Javascript/JQuery function...

```
function go()
{
   var url = $('#url').val();
   var user = $('input[name="user"]').val();
   $.post('urlin.php', { url: url, user: user }, function(data ) {
        // handle post
   });
}
```

Comment: I just need to send an extra parameter, how can i incorporate this into my existing code and the field i am trying to send is hidden

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. The above grabs the values from the #url element and the hidden element. These are then posted to the urlin.php script. See [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 2):

You can just modify your `go` function to accept an extra parameter:

```
function go(url, user) {
    ...
}
```

In your input fields, add an id to the hidden field, and modify `go` function call to something like `go($('#url').val(), $('#user').val());`:

```
<input type="text" size="85" placeholder="Enter a URL to shorten." name="url" id="url" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13 || event.which == 13) { go($('#url').val(), $('#user').val()); }" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['auth']; ?>">
<input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Shorten" border="0" onclick="go($('#url').val(), $('#user').val());" />
```